# python csv module quotes

Tags: python-3.x, csv, module

I have a problem with the csv module in Python, I need to sort directories - they are organized like this and below you see how it looks:

```
dirA                    #DirectoryA
dirB                    #DirectoryB
  "subdirA, subsubdirA" #subdirA is under dirB and subsubdirA is 
                        #under subdirA 
  "subdirB"             #subdirB under dirB
dirC
  "subdirA"             #subdirA under dirC
###################################################
001, dirA
002, dirB
003, "subdirA, subsubdirA"
004, "subdirA, subsubdirB"
005, dirC
006, "subdirB"
```

while csv-reading the file the quotes in the Python list are deleted- no chance to work on the complete data of the file.
what Python makes is:

```
dirA            
dirB            
subdirA
subsubdirA 
subdirB
dirC
subdirA
```

Do you have an idea how to get it running?
Thx

Comment: this is likely a result of the default dialect the `csv` module being the `"Excel"` dialect..

Comment: what does your file look like? are the indents before `"subdirA, ...` etc. tabs or spaces? what is your desired output?

Comment: my file looks like this- no indents, not one line, but comments are single-lined here.. i modified the main question already
    001, dirA "\n"
    002, dirB "\n"
    003, "subdirA, subsubdirA" "\n"
    004, "subdirA, subsubdirB" "\n"
    005, dirC "\n"
    006, "subdirB" "\n"

Comment: do you have newlines or is the file all one line?

Comment: This seems less and less like a csv file, which makes me think you may be better off parsing it by reading the file as a string..

Comment: and how to threat the quotes ' " ' ?